# How to render JSON response as dropdown list in React

Tags: json, reactjs, dropdown

I'm currently trying to take some JSON data that I've received from an API and put that into a dropdown in a very simple React application.

This is my DropDown component thus far:

```
import React from 'react';

var values;

fetch('http://localhost:8080/values')
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        values = json;
        console.log(values);
    });

class DropDown extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div className="drop-down">
            <p>I would like to render a dropdown here from the values object</p>
            </div>;
    }
}

export default DropDown;
```

Any my JSON looks like this:

```
{  
   "values":[  
      {  
         "id":0,
         "name":"Jeff"
      },
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Joe"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"John"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "name":"Billy"
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "name":"Horace"
      },
      {  
         "id":5,
         "name":"Greg"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like the dropdown options to correspond to the 'name' of each element, and the 'id' to be used as an element identifier when an event is triggered by selecting an option. Any advice on getting this data into a dropdown which responds to user input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can iterate over `values` of the JSON with `.map` to build your `<select>` and `<options>` and use `onChange` for `<select>`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Not yet. Could you give me a quick example of how it's used?

Comment: As in the below answer, make sure to make an api call in componentdidmount which is one of the best method to make API calls

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

var values;

class DropDown extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            options: []
        }  
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchOptions()
    }

    fetchOptions(){
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/values')
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            }).then((json) => {
                values = json;
                this.setState({options: values.values})
                console.log(values);
            });
    }
    render(){
        return <div className="drop-down">
            <select>
                { this.state.options.map((option, key) => <option key={key} >{option}</option>) }
            </select>
            </div>;
    }
}

export default DropDown;
```

Basically you are initializing state and setting `options` to null.

You are then fetching your options when the component mounts in the browser. These values are set to your state with `this.setState()`.

Note: It is important to make any API calls in `componentDidMount()` and not `componentWillMount()`. If you call it in `componentWillMount()` the request will be made twice.

Then you render these options by mapping them in your render function

Comment: Thanks Stretch. I'm getting some errors when I run this: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:10)

   5 | class DropDown extends React.Component {
   6 | 
>  7 |     state = {
     |           ^
   8 |         options: null
   9 |     }
  10 |

Comment: @HomerPlata I have updated to use a constructor instead. Try updating your code to match mine by setting the state inside the constructor function

Comment: @HomerPlata just updated again but best to initialize options as an empty array

Comment: Now I'm seeing: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

Comment: Ah yes, you need to use lambda functions instead so that the context of `this` refers to the class and is not scoped to the function you are calling `this` in. @HomerPlata have updated the example for you

Comment: Now it's saying: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.options.map is not a function. I do really appreciate all this help by the way.

Comment: Have you initialised `options` as an array or is it still set to `null`? As in how I have 
`this.state = {
            options: []
        }  `

Comment: Yep, I've run your code exactly. Do I need to declare options elsewhere too?

Comment: What is getting returned from your API call? Is it an array or an object? If it is an object, you will not be able to map your result. Can you update your API to return an array instead?

Comment: Sorry to continue with the noob questions, but how can I make it return an array instead? Is there no way to use the response in its current form?

Comment: Maybe post that as a separate question as it is unrelated to your original post. If my answer answered your original question please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: I'll answer it correct if you can hard-code some content for 'options' that will result in the dropdown being rendered

Comment: Have updated where you set state in the fetch callback

Comment: Thanks Stretch. Still not quite working. I now get: Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. and a further error of: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Comment: Yes, you need to add a key to the elements you return in a loop. You can easily find more information on this of you Google the error but I have updated my example.

Comment: Not been able to check it until I get home, I’ve not forgotten. I will mark the answer as accepted later, thanks for your help.

Comment: It still won't work for me. I'm abandoning React for now and defaulting to old school JavaScript. I've voted up your answer for the help you have given me, but can't tag it as the accepted answer because I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Call the API in `componentDidMount` lifecycle function of your React component and then save the response in state and then render the Select dropdown

```js
import React from 'react';

class DropDown extends React.Component {
    state = {
        values: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       fetch('http://localhost:8080/values')
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then((json)=> {
            this.setState({
               values: json
            })
        });
    }
    render(){
        return <div className="drop-down">
            <p>I would like to render a dropdown here from the values object</p>
              <select>{
                 this.state.values.map((obj) => {
                     return <option value={obj.id}>{obj.name}</option>
                 })
              }</select>
            </div>;
    }
}

export default DropDown;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
JSON FILE: terrifcalculatordata.json
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vigo",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mercedes",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Lexus",
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Buggati",
      },
]

CODE: 
1st import json file on top:

import calculatorData from "../static/data/terrifcalculatordata.json";

2nd in render method type this code: 

                      <Form>
                            <FormGroup>
                              <Input
                              type="select"
                              onChange = {this.changeCarmodel}
                              value={this.state.changeCar}
                              >
                              {calculatorData.map((caldata, index) =>
                                <option 
                                key={index}
                                value= {caldata.id}
                                > {caldata.name} </option>
                              )}
                              </Input>
                            </FormGroup>
                         </Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to render JSON response as dropdown list in React.

```
export default class ExpenseNew extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            PickerSelectedVal : '',
            accountnameMain:[],
        }
    }
     componentDidMount(){
         var account_nam=[]
                fetch('your Url', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + your token }
                })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((customerselect) => {
                        // alert(JSON.stringify(customerselect)) 
                        global.customerdata = JSON.stringify(customerselect)
                        var customername = JSON.parse(customerdata);
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(customername));
                        for (i = 0; i < customername.cus_data.length; i++) {
                            var dataa = customername.cus_data[i]["account_name"];  
                            account_nam.push(dataa)
                        }
                        this.setState({accountnameMain:account_nam});
                    })
                    .done();
    }
                    render() {
                          return (
                               <Picker
                                selectedValue={this.state.PickerSelectedVal}
                                placeholder="Select your customer"
                                mode="dropdown"
                                iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerSelectedVal: itemValue})} >

                                {this.state.accountnameMain.map((item, key)=>(
                                    <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={key}/>)
                                )}

                            </Picker>


)
}


}
```